# News App/ RSS Feed and XML

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I am creating a news app for android wear and have been stuck on this nigel for months. I know what a RSS feed and all that is.

This is the BBC news tech fee http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml

I can display the description of the feed in my app but that is about 1 sentence. I want to get all the content from the article and save it to a string variable or a file. I need to take this string anf put it through a algorithm that I have made. Heres a example,

A atricle has this descripition in the rss

> EE, the UK's largest mobile phone operator, is fined £1m by the
>   regulator Ofcom for breaching rules on handling customer complaints.

But the real article looks like this.

> EE, the UK's largest mobile phone operator, has been fined £1m by the
>   regulator Ofcom for breaching rules on handling customer complaints.
>
> Ofcom said from 2011 to 2014, the firm did not provide its customers
>   with full information about their right to take complaints to an
>   independent body.
>
> EE should have informed customers about this in writing, but did not,
>   it found.
>
> The investigation into EE is part of Ofcom's wider look at complaints
>   handling by telecoms companies.
>
> EE stressed that the fine related to historic conduct.
>
> "While this in no way excuses it, it is important to note that we
>   identified issues in our complaints handling and began our programme
>   to tackle these problems head-on in 2013, before Ofcom started their
>   investigation," a spokesperson for the company said.
>
> "We have made considerable improvements since then. Ofcom's current
>   figures highlight that complaints into Ofcom about EE have fallen by
>   50% in the past year." 'Deadlock'
>
> EE customers have the right to take complaints that cannot be resolved
>   to an independent body up to two months after the complaint is first
>   made.
>
> Between 22 July 2011 and 8 April 2014, Ofcom found that a number of
>   customers who had requested a "deadlock letter" as a precursor to
>   referring their complaint to the independent body never received such
>   a letter.
>
> It also found that EE did not notify some customers on their paper
>   bills that they could refer any complaint to this body free of charge.
>
> "It's vital that customers can access all the information they need
>   when they're pursuing a complaint," said Ofcom's Claudio Pollack.
>
> "Ofcom imposes strict rules on how providers must handle complaints
>   and treats any breach of these rules very seriously. The fine imposed
>   against EE takes account of the serious failings that occurred in the
>   company's complaints handling, and the extended period over which
>   these took place."
>
> The regulator said EE had 20 days to pay the penalty, which would then
>   be passed on the UK Treasury.

I can get the top descripition working but I cant get the text like the second one. Im not a newbie, im not asking for the completed code. I really wouldnt want this to get closed down. This problem has set back my app by months. I have looked at many librarys but none of them doing what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Erm, that xml file has the entry for the article, you just have to extract it then use it get the article.

Comment: How would I go about extracting the article from the RSS file?

Comment: added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rss file is an xml document. Here is an extact from it

```
   <item> 
      <title>Facebook to pay video clip creators</title>  
      <description>Facebook is to start sharing revenue from advertising with video creators.</description>  
      <link>http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-33362722#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&amp;ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa</link>  
      <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-33362722</guid>  
      <pubDate>Thu, 02 Jul 2015 13:45:27 GMT</pubDate>  
      <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/17D36/production/_84009579_fbook.jpg"/>  
      <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://c.files.bbci.co.uk/218E/production/_84009580_fbook.jpg"/> 
    </item>
```

So you parse the document through something like Sax or Dom, extract each item element which would be the article meta data. From within the item element you extract the link element which you extract the actual url from and use that to retrieve the article.

Comment: Within my code I have a why to extract the link, I then need to extract the article from that link right? Thanks that makes me understand it more

Comment: yw and please accept the answer so others can find the solution.

Comment: oh, bear in mind that the link usually addresses a final html document, not just a body of text.